# how to plot different types of charts using plotly and make_subplot in python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, pie-chart

I want to plot mixed subplots of pie chart and bar chart how to do it ?

Until now I am able to plot the pie charts but how to add the bar chart ?

The code below is perform a *groupby* function and iterate over the returned object in order to subplot several pie charts based on unique values of the groupby object.

## dataframe:

```
   event_type      date        event_mohafaza  number_person   groups
0   watch movie   2020-08-14             loc1          25       group1
1   stay at home  2020-08-14             loc3          32       group1
2   watch movie   2020-08-14             loc2          45       group2
3   swimming      2020-08-14             loc4          12       group1
4   stay at home  2020-08-14             loc2          45       group3
5   watch movie   2019-06-14             loc5          22       group1
6   watch movie   2020-08-14             loc2          10       group4
7   watch movie   2020-08-14             loc1          44       group1
8   stay at home  2020-08-14             loc3          22       group3
9   swimming      2020-08-14             loc2          32       group2
10  watch movie   2019-09-14             loc1          17       group1
11  camping       2020-08-14             loc4          27       group1
12  watch movie   2020-08-14             loc5          43       group3
13  meeting       2019-06-14             loc2          33       group2
14  camping       2020-08-14             loc1          21       group4
```

## code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# data for this example
import plotly.express as px


lst = list(df.groupby('event_mohafaza  '))


# here we want our grid to be 2 x 3
rows = 2
cols = 3
# continents are the first element in l
subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]

# a compact and general version of what you did
specs = [[{'type':'domain'}]* cols] * rows

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs,
        print_grid=True)


for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    # basic math to get col and row
    row = i // cols + 1
    col = i % (rows + 1) + 1
    # this is the dataframe for every continent
    d = l[1]
   
        fig.add_trace(
        go.Pie(labels=d["event_type"],
               values = d["number_person"],
               hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
               showlegend=True,
               textposition='inside',
               rotation=90
              ),
         row=row,
         col=col
        
    
    )
#     fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=df.event_type, opacity=0.3), 1, 1)
    
fig.update_layout(title="Population by Continent", title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please include a sample dataframe.

Comment: @vestland i will edit my question and add dataframe sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We modified the code with the understanding that we were adding a sixth bar chart. It's not clear what kind of bar chart you want to add, so I've set it up as you see fit. The point is that you need to specify a graph that matches the subplot structure.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# data for this example
import plotly.express as px

lst = list(df.groupby('event_mohafaza'))

# here we want our grid to be 2 x 3
rows = 2
cols = 3
# continents are the first element in l
subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]

# a compact and general version of what you did
# specs = [[{'type':'domain'}]* cols] * rows
specs = [[{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"}],[{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "bar"}]]
fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs,
        print_grid=True)

for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    # basic math to get col and row
    row = i // cols + 1
    col = i % (rows + 1) + 1
    # this is the dataframe for every continent
    d = l[1]
   
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=d["event_type"],
                         values = d["number_person"],
                         hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
                         showlegend=True,
                         textposition='inside',
                         rotation=90),
     row=row,
     col=col    
    )
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.groups, y=df.number_person, opacity=0.3, showlegend=False), row=2, col=3)
    
fig.update_layout(title="Population by Continent", title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i tried your answer and i have several questions if you can explain to me

Comment: I'll answer to the best of my knowledge, but what is it about?

Comment: 1: how to change the size of the charts ?
2: how to make the row and columns flexible based on the length of the distinct values of the column.

Comment: I have a question about the groupby function so i think its not related to this question right i will open another question about it can you help me ?

Comment: You can change the size of the graph with `fig.update_layout(height=800,width=1200,...) `

Comment: The only flexible way to determine rows and columns is to calculate the number of rows from the number of columns to the total number of graphs.

Comment: I try to make the rows flexible as: `rows = len(lst)`
how to change the `specs` parameters ???
 
the system crash and display the below error


`ValueError: 
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (5 x 3).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'}], [{'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'bar'}]]`

Comment: Since all of your code was specified here with 'type:Domain', I specified the matrix structure in the list Example [[A,B,C],[D,E,F]]. If you look at the official documentation, it was an optional item, so it may not be necessary. Please try it without it.

Comment: i tried this but still not working :
`rows = len(lst)
 cols = 3
# specs = [[{'type':'domain'}]* cols] * rows
specs = [[{"type": "pie"}]* cols * rows ,[{"type": "bar"}]]`

it display the below error:
`ValueError: 
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (5 x 3).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'},...], [{'type': 'bar'}]]`

Comment: I checked the [official page](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html) again because I got an error. You need to set up the matrix structure of the subplot in list format.